# Is there a predicate for #inst?

Tags: clojurescript

Is there a predicate for #inst?

```
dev:cljs.user=> #inst "1985-04-12"
#inst "1985-04-12T00:00:00.000-00:00"

dev:cljs.user=> (type #inst "1985-04-12")
#object[Date]

dev:cljs.user=> (tagged-literal? #inst "1985-04-12")
false
```

, so that `(answer-to-this-question? #inst "1985-04-12")` returns `true`?

If such a predicate does not exist, can one be made?

So far I've come up with:

```
(= "function Date() { [native code] }" (-> #inst "1985-04-12" type str))
;; -> true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also you can use `instance?` function in **any** version of ClojureScript:

```
(instance? js/Date #inst "2017-11-14")
;; -> true
```

Answer (score 3):

[`inst?`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/inst_q) was added in Clojure 1.9.
It is also available in Clojurescript since [73ab8ff8f](https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/commit/73ab8ff8f4610a6f11cf64cc09e7173dcada5dc0) which landed in Clojurescript mid 2016.